# How to add strings to array using a for loop?

Tags: ios

I want to add a few strings to an array. the strings have a variable part like "test1" , "test2" , "test3" and so on. I thought using a for loop would be a good idea but i get some errors.

here is the code:

```
for (int i=0; i<19; i++) {

    [detailImageArray addObject:@"army%@.jpg",i];

}
```

Comment: This is not related to Xcode. ----- You may want to use the `+ [NSString stringWithFormat:]` method. Don't assume you can use format strings *everywhere* -- you can't.

Comment: @H2CO3 ok but why did you give it a negative point? Only for a wrong tag? Dude i am new to stackoverflow chill out!

Comment: No, it's rather the lack of research effort.

Comment: @H2CO3 I searched every page i could find here and anywhere else on web. I know we are all supposed to keep this website at a high standard but don't you think this is too much? I respect what you doing by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` method as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
    [detailImageArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"army%d.jpg",i];
}
```